# Samsung Note 8 & Android 9.0 Browser shows the wrong CSS colour

Tags: android, css, mobile, samsung-mobile, mobile-browser

my website shows the wrong color on the Samsung note 8 & android 9.0 browser.
I have a light blue color, it shows dark blue color, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you a bluelight filter enabled on your phone ? It got me upset for a long time before I figured out that the blue appeared purple for a reason xD

Bye !

Comment: Thanks, where are the settings of the filter? On chrome, it ok but on the Samsung browser not.

Comment: I was talking about your phone's bluefilter, but if it's okay on one navigator but not on the other, it should not be a bluefilter problem !